# using local less with npm

Tags: npm, less, package.json

Are there any established patterns for running less via npm scripts?

for instance, in my package.json file I have:

```
{
  "name": "lesstest",
  "description": "less test",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build:css": "./node_modules/less/bin/lessc src/less/app.less dist/style.css"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "less": "^2.6.0",
  }
}
```

running:

```
./node_modules/less/bin/lessc src/less/app.less dist/style.css
```

from terminal works just fine, but when I run

npm run build:css

I get " '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. "  Does this mean that commands in npm scripts cannot include paths? If so, are there any techniques out there to execute a similar intention without using gulp?

Answer (score 4):

You can just use `"lessc src/less/app.less dist/style.css"`

By default, package.json looks in your node_modules folder, and if it can't find it, looks elsewhere, so you can safely use a downloaded dependency as if you had globally installed it.

Comment: @OussamaEssamadi Please see my answer for clarification. You cannot run it in the command line but the line has to be part of the `scripts` section of your `package.json`.

Comment: @Sandro I found out later on that I could make use of **npx**.

Answer (score 2):

I just want to clarify  @JRJurman's answer a bit. You can use `lessc` like this:

```
{
  "name": "lesstest",
  "description": "less test",
  "scripts": {
    "build:css": "lessc src/less/app.less > dist/style.css"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "less": "^3.0.0",
  }
}
```

As a more comprehensive pattern for less in npm: You often need to also integrate less file dependencies. The `package.json` would look like this:

```
{
  "name": "lesstest",
  "description": "less test",
  "scripts": {
    "build:css": "lessc src/less/app.less > dist/style.css"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "less": "^3.0.0",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@foo/bar": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

and in your local `baz.less` file you would refer to the dependency like this:

```
@import "@foo/bar/src/a-less-file";
```

- `@foo` refers to the respective folder within your `node_modules`
  folder and `bar/src` are the nested folders.
- `a-less-file` refers
  to `a-less-file.less` within your `node_modules/@foo/bar/src`